# Always on high availability groups option is grayed out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to enable the Always on HA groups using SQL 2016 STD, but the option is grayed out as shown below

[image]

any hints on how to enable it would be appreciated.

Regards,

Hussein

Comment: Please, run this query and add output to your question: select @@version;

Comment: The other problem you have is you mentioned you're running Standard Edition but AlwaysOn Availability Groups is an Enterprise-only feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do that.
From Microsoft documentation:

> Prior to SQL Server 2017, and Windows Server 2016, the instance had to
> reside on a Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC) node to enable the
> Always On availability group feature

And in your image is indicated SQL Server does not reside on a Failover Cluster.
Upgrade to sql 2017 or implement a Failover cluster.

Comment: you just nailed it, many thanks.